# Font awsome icons are showing codes in squares instead of icons

Tags: font-awesome

I am new in web development. I have downloaded a free template with all sources and trying to change it for having some experience. When i run the template, the fa fa-facebook, fa fa-twitter etc icons are showing codes like f0 98 etc in square and the icons of facebook and twitter are not showing. Kindly help!. 
Here is the code to link font-awsome

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libraries/fonts/font-awesome.min.css">
```

here is the code

```
 <!-- Header Socials -->
 <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 header-socials">
 <ul class="no-padding">
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i></a></li>
 <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>                        
 </ul>
 <a href="contact.html" class="contact-us"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Contact Us</a>
 </div><!-- / Header Socials -->
```

Regards!
Akhtar

Comment: In a level of detail similar to your question..... It looks like there is a problem in your code. Most likely to do with how you're trying to use font-awesome. (You should post your code if you need help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you have fully implemented Font Awesome

Try putting this inside `<head>`:

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/08a9781b65.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```